# Json4S creating new object with updated value

Tags: scala, json4s

I am trying to update a specific field in a json object, the structure looks like this:

```
{ "foo": [
    { 
      "bar": {
        "ref": "ref to ignore", 
        "baz": { 
          "ref": "my_old_value"
 }}}]}
```

I am parsing this object with Json4S, using Jackson, and would like to create a new json object with the value of this specific "ref" field changed to a different value. I can display the current ref object:

```
[scala> json.\("foo")(0).\("bar").\("baz")
res6: JObject(List((ref,JString(my_old_value))))
```

And I am able to use a transform/transformField function to generate a new object, I'll spare the details of the transform:

```
[scala> val transformed = json.\("foo")(0).\("bar").\("baz").transform { ..
transformed: JObject(List((ref,JString(my_new_value))))
```

I can not seem to figure out the correct way to create a new object in which he original 'ref' object has been replaced with the transformed 'ref' object in the overall json object. I also need to note that in my actual json object there are many 'ref' objects, i only need to update the specific one located at `json.\("foo")(0).\("bar").\("baz").("ref")`

I've tried both using the replace and flatMap functions to do this but cannot get it to work properly. Can anyone provide some advice on how to do this with Json4S?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Like most libs in Scala, json4s works with immutability. There is no way to change a value inside a JValue, but you can create a new one with changes (like case classes copy).

If you want to change every "ref" field you can use a mapField with pattern matching.

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

val str = """{ "foo": [
    {
      "bar": {
        "baz": {
          "ref": "my_old_value"
 }}}]}"""

val json = parse(str)

val updated = json.mapField {
  case ("foo", JArray(head :: tail)) => ("foo", JArray(head.mapField {
    case ("ref", JString("my_old_value")) => ("ref", JString("new value"))
    case otherwise => otherwise
  } :: tail))
  case otherwise => otherwise
}

println(updated)

// JObject(List((foo,JArray(List(JObject(List((bar,JObject(List((baz,JObject(List((ref,JString(new value)))))))))))))))
```

EDIT

I modified replace method in order to add support to arrays, now you can modify all elements in an array through "foo[]" or a particular element "foo[index]". Add this implicit class in your scope.

```
implicit class JValueOps(underlying:JValue) {

  object ArrayIndex {
    val R = """^([^\[]+)\[(\d+)\]""".r
    def unapply(str: String): Option[(String, Int)] = str match {
      case R(name, index) => Option(name, index.toInt)
      case _ => None
    }
  }

  object ArrayAll {
    val R = """^([^\[]+)\[\]""".r
    def unapply(str: String): Option[String] = str match {
      case R(name) => Option(name)
      case _ => None
    }
  }

  def replace2(l: List[String], replacement: JValue): JValue = {

    def rep(l: List[String], in: JValue): JValue = {

      (l, in) match {

        // eg "foo[0]"
        case (ArrayIndex(name, index) :: Nil, JObject(fields)) => JObject(
          fields.map {
            case JField(`name`, JArray(array)) if array.length > index => JField(name, JArray(array.updated(index, replacement)))
            case field => field
          }
        )

        // eg "foo[0]" "bar"
        case (ArrayIndex(name, index) :: xs, JObject(fields)) => JObject(
          fields.map {
            case JField(`name`, JArray(array)) if array.length > index => JField(name, JArray(array.updated(index, rep(xs, array(index)))))
            case field => field
          }
        )

        // eg "foo[]"
        case (ArrayAll(name) :: Nil, JObject(fields)) => JObject(
          fields.map {
            case JField(`name`, JArray(array)) => JField(name, JArray(array.map(_ => replacement)))
            case field => field
          }
        )

        // eg "foo[]" "bar"
        case (ArrayAll(name) :: xs, JObject(fields)) => JObject(
          fields.map {
            case JField(`name`, JArray(array)) => JField(name, JArray(array.map( elem => rep(xs, elem))))
            case field => field
          }
        )

        // eg "foo"
        case (x :: Nil, JObject(fields)) => JObject(
          fields.map {
            case JField(`x`, value) ⇒ JField(x, replacement)
            case field ⇒ field
          }
        )

        // eg "foo" "bar"
        case (x :: xs, JObject(fields)) => JObject(
          fields.map {
            case JField(`x`, value) ⇒ JField(x, rep(xs, value))
            case field ⇒ field
          }
        )

        case _ => in

      }

    }

    rep(l, underlying)
  }

}
```

Then you can do

```
json.replace2("foo[0]" :: "bar" :: "baz" :: "ref" :: Nil, JString("new value"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand immutability and that I need to create a new object, I've edited the title. I do not need to change all ref fields in the object, just the specific one at `json.\("foo")(0).\("bar").\("baz")` There are actually many ref objects in my actual json.

Comment: I changed my code. Now I'm applying "ref" mapField to the first element of foo array.

I wish I could use replace, but I've been looking it's implementations, it doesn't take in count arrays. Maybe I can change that, I'll try it in a while.

Comment: Here you are, an improve replace method that works as you need

Comment: I created a Pull Request with this functionality
https://github.com/json4s/json4s/pull/540